# Angular universal npm run serve:ssr throw error : package.json does not exist

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

i'm trying to render my app with ssr locally but i face some issues.

**1. npm run build:ssr**

**2. npm run serve:ssr**

> Error: package.json does not exist at
>   /Users/imade/nubuwah/dist/package.json

I don't really know what to do, thanks in advance.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.25
Node: 12.14.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core                       8.3.25
@angular-devkit/schematics                 8.3.25
@angular/cdk                               7.3.7
@angular/cli                               8.3.25
@angular/fire                              5.4.2
@angular/material                          7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                           8.3.25
@nguniversal/express-engine                8.2.6
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.2.6
@schematics/angular                        8.3.25
@schematics/update                         0.803.25
rxjs                                       6.5.4
typescript                                 3.4.5
webpack                                    4.39.2
```

**Angular.json**

https://pastebin.com/hRs2UJPH

**package.json**

https://pastebin.com/Ly6aWHC6

Comment: Which steps throws this error, is it the build? Can you show your package.json and angular.json files?

Comment: @David the second one, i have edited the post with the json files

Comment: Can you remove `--bundleDependencies all` and try again?

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` should not be inside `dist` folder and you need to run `npm run server:ssr` from project's root folder.

Comment: Yes it isn't inside but, dist folder is generate, the package.json don't get generated.
If i add manually the package.json i face this error : 

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/imade/nubuwah/dist/package.json'

Comment: do you run `npm run serve:ssr` inside `dist` folder or project's root? I'm trying to understand why something expects package.json to be in dist

Comment: pwd
/Users/imade/nubuwah

from root

Comment: looks like it is known issue and discussed here https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1207